# How can I upload files without using an HTML <form>?

Tags: javascript, jquery, http, upload

in a web application I am building I need to upload photos without using a form, otherwise it will come up with form embedded in an outer from which is not permitted in XHTML.

I think uploading files is what jQuery.post should be able to do, but I currently can't figure out how to do this using jQuery.

Comment: Why is XHTML significant in uploading a file?

Comment: XHTML does not allow nested form.

Comment: ...for good reason. is there a way you can possibly avoid nesting forms?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

take a look at [swfupload](http://swfupload.org/), it's a pretty nifty little app that should accomplish what you want. otherwise, you could separate out the forms, and just use css/javascript to reposition them if necessary.

Answer (score 2):

With [jQuery.post](http://docs.jquery.com/Ajax/jQuery.post) you will be only able to send key/value pairs to the server in a POST Request, However you can use plugins like [jQuery Multiple File Upload Plugin](http://www.fyneworks.com/jquery/multiple-file-upload/).

Answer (score 0):

Have you check out the fieldset element? Why not wrap your input elements in that, then use jQuery to dynamically assign 'submit' functionality, as opposed to trying to attach it to the overall form element?

Answer (score 0):

I can confirm that jquery.fileupload does not need a form to upload an image, in fact the file upload fields (which fileupload wants) can be in a form, you have to use the manual aspects such as defining you url: for where the file will be sent, and probably the add: event.

Just a note, and I'm quite sure that my use is probably a little wrong, but the other form elements along with all the file upload data will be sent, but it's trivial to simply get the file data and ignore the rest. And yes my form submission for all the other non-file-upload fields work fine with my submit action. Hope this helps.